# Is there any way to not get undefined in output when not returning a function

Tags: javascript

I'm solving the challenges in hacker rank and while working with one challenges in that problem i haven't specified any return statement since i don't want to return anything but  just the function to print something on the console. Later while executing, the output is showing undefined and some console statements.

```
function isPositive(a) {
    try {
        if (a > 0)
            console.log('YES');
        else if (a === 0)
            throw "error1"
        else if (a < 0)
            throw "error2"
    }
    catch (err)
    {
        if(err == "error1")
            console.log('Zero Error');
        else if (err == "error2")
            console.log('Negative Error');
    }
}
```

Expected
YES
YES
YES

Actual output
YES
undefined
YES
undefined
YES
undefined

Comment: I think you need the return the strings instead of logging them in console. They usually have code already written to log the return value of your function. That's why it's logging `undefined` because you are returning nothing from your function so return value is `undefined`, and your `console.log` is printing `YES`. Replace your console logs with return

Comment: No, there's no way, functions implicitly always return `undefined` unless the return value is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working when i changed the console statements to return.

```
function isPositive(a) {
    try {
        if (a > 0)
             return 'YES';
        else if (a === 0)
            throw "error1"
        else if (a < 0)
            throw "error2"
    }
    catch (err)
    {
        if(err === "error1")
           return 'Zero Error';
        else if (err === "error2")
            return 'Negative Error';
    }
}
```